# ZIP on the fly immediatelly

Tags: java, servlets, zip

I need to generate a ZIP file with data on the fly from a servlet. I pass the ServletOutputSream to the ZipOutputStream constructor, and it does and send  the ZIP to the client correctly. When the ZIP result is large, the servlet takes to answer a lot. I suppose that first creates the ZIP and after send it.

I make a helper class that wraps ZipOutputStream.

I need that when the flush method is called, the ZIP piece that is already generated, will be sent immediatelly. How can I do this?

```
public class ZIPResponse {

    private ZipOutputStream out;
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    private boolean isFirstEntry;
    private ConnectionManager con;

    public ZIPResponse(ConnectionManager con, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        this.out = new ZipOutputStream(out);
        isFirstEntry = true;
        this.con = con;
    }

    public ZIPResponse(ConnectionManager con, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        this(con, response.getOutputStream());
        this.response = response;
        response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        sendNewEntry("con");
        flush();
    }

    public void sendNewEntry(String dataName) throws IOException {
        if (isFirstEntry) {
            isFirstEntry = false;
        } else {
            out.closeEntry();
        }
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(dataName));
    }

    public void sendData(String dataName, String data) throws IOException {
        sendNewEntry(dataName);
        sendData(data);
    }

    public void sendData(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        out.write(bytes);
        flush();
    }

    public void sendData(String data) throws IOException {
        sendData(data.getBytes());
    }

    public void sendAndCloseData(String dataName, String data) throws IOException {
        sendNewEntry(dataName);
        sendData(data);
        close();
    }

    private void sendDataFile(String dataName, DataTransformer dt)
            throws IOException, SQLException {
        sendNewEntry(dataName);
        dt.sendResultSet(this);
    }

    public void sendDataFile(String dataName, ResultSet data, String[] columnsRestriction) throws IOException,
            SQLException {
        RestrictedDataTransformer dt = new RestrictedDataTransformer(data, columnsRestriction);
        sendDataFile(dataName, dt);
    }

    public void sendDataFile(String dataName, ResultSet data) throws IOException,
            SQLException {
        DataTransformer dt = new DataTransformer(data);
        sendDataFile(dataName, dt);
    }

    public void sendDataFile(String dataName, PreparedStatement p) throws
            SQLException, IOException {
        ResultSet data = p.executeQuery();
        sendDataFile(dataName, data);
    }


    public void sendDataFile(String dataName, String SQL, String[] columnsRestricted)
            throws DBException, SQLException, IOException {
        ResultSetStatement st = new ResultSetStatement(con, SQL);
        ResultSet valores = st.executeQuery();
        try {
            sendDataFile(dataName, valores, columnsRestricted);
        } finally {
            valores.close();
        }
    }

    public void sendDataFile(String dataName, String SQL) throws DBException, SQLException, IOException {
        ResultSetStatement st = new ResultSetStatement(con, SQL);
        ResultSet valores = st.executeQuery();
        try {
            sendDataFile(dataName, valores);
        } finally {
            valores.close();
        }
    }

    public void sendAndCloseDataFile(String dataName, ResultSet data) throws
            SQLException, IOException {
        sendDataFile(dataName, data);
        close();
    }

    public void sendAndCloseDataFile(String dataName, String SQL) throws DBException, SQLException, IOException {
        sendDataFile(dataName, SQL);
        close();
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        sendNewEntry("OK");
        out.closeEntry();
        out.close();
        flush();
    }

    public void flush() throws IOException {       
      out.flush();
      response.flushBuffer();
    }
}
```

Comment: You web server (and client) will need to support sending of "chunked" responses as the length will not be known before sending the data.

Answer (score 4):

In case your client is flexible with what it receives, GZIP will work better for streaming compression.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation:

```
String realpath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fi.replace('/', '-')+"_"+ff.replace('/', '-')+".zip");
ServletOutputStream out = null;
ZipOutputStream zipfile = null;
try{
                List<Object[]> cfdis = /*my hibernate criteria source, your Database?*/

        out = response.getOutputStream();

        zipfile = new ZipOutputStream(out);
        ZipEntry zipentry = null;

        for(Object[] cfdi:cfdis){

            zipentry = new ZipEntry(cfdi[1].toString()+".xml");
            zipfile.putNextEntry(zipentry);

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(realpath+cfdi[0].toString()));


            byte[] bytes = new byte[FILEBUFFERSIZE];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                zipfile.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
}catch(...){}
finally{
   zipfile.close();
   out.close();
}
```

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: I fail to see how exactly this solves the OP's problem of the `ZipOutputStream` being fully buffered in memory until the last bit. Can you please elaborate a bit more on that part?

Comment: You aren't store the content of the zip in memory (just small byte[]'s that are garbage collected), there are only streams, and the container is sending chunks because we didn't provide a response lenght (size defined in the java ee container) of the ZipOutputStream via the ServletOutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is to send the zip content to response before you complete the zip creation. Yes, you can do this thru buffering.

For buffering follow [Streaming large files in a java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709/streaming-large-files-in-a-java-servlet)