# Reliable data serving

Tags: java, servlets, fileserver

How can i make sure my file serving is reliable and scalable? How many parallel request it can handle?

I am thinking beyond the hardware capability and band width.

i am following [Streaming large files in a java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709/streaming-large-files-in-a-java-servlet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those are static files, just link to it *directly*. All decent servletcontainers/appservers have a well-developed `DefaultServlet`. If those are static files located *outside* the webapplication from where you'd link them to, then you can also just add the root folder of those files as another context. It's unclear which server you're using, but if it were Tomcat, you could just add a new `<Context>` to `server.xml`:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/static/files" path="/files" />
```

This way it's accessible by `http://example.com/files/...`.

If those are dynamically generated files or files coming from a database, then you need to develop a servlet which does the IO job efficiently: i.e. do not unnecessarily store the entire data in memory (e.g. in a `ByteArrayInputStream` or `byte[]` before emitting them to the output. Just write the bytes **immediately** to the output as it comes in. You may find this those examples of a [basic fileservlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html) and a more [advanced fileservlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) (supporting resumes and so on) useful.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, 9 years later and I found this answer. What if I need to perform scaling or other processing on the server before sending it to the user i.e. after fetching it from the database. I would not be able to avoid loading the whole image into memory before doing that. The client may request for a thumbnail, an averagely sized image, the full image etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just serving static files from a file system just use Apache - it's going to be better then anything you will write yourself.