# Methods for serving files through Servlets

Tags: java, database, servlets, filesystems, io

For the sake of brevity consider a facebook style image content serving app. Users can upload content as well as access content shared by other people. I am looking at best ways of handling this kind of file serving application through Java servlets. There is surprisingly little information available on the topic. I'd appreciate if someone can tell me their personal experiences on a small setup (a few hundred users).

So far I am tempted to use the database as a file system (using mongodb) but the approach seems cumbersome and tedious and will need replicating part of the functionality already provided by OS native filesystems. I don't want to use commercial software or have the bandwidth to write my own like facebook. All I want is to be able to do this through free software on a small server with a RAID or something similar. A solution that scales well to multiple servers would be a plus. The important thing is to serve it through java servlets (I am willing to look into alternatives but they have to be usable through java).

I'd appreciate any help. Any references to first hand experiences would be helpful as well. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reliable data serving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502841/reliable-data-serving)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guru -

I set up something exactly like this for members of my extended family to share photos. It is a slightly complicated process that includes the following:

1) Sign up for Amazon Web Services, notably their S3 (Simple Storage Service). There is a free storage tier that should cover the amount of users you described.

2) Set up a web application that accepts uploads.  I use [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) in combination with jQuery and ajax, to upload to a servlet that accepts, scans, logs, and does whatever else I want with the file(s). On the servlet side, I use [ESAPI'](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Enterprise_Security_API#tab=Java_EE)s upload validation mechanism, part of the validation engine, which is just built on top of [Commons File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/), which I have also used by itself.

3) After processing the file(s) appropriately, I use [JetS3t](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) as my Java-AmazonS3 API and upload the file to Amazon S3.  At that point, users can download or view photos depending on their level of access.  The easiest way I have found to do this is to use JetS3t in combination with the Web Application Authentication to create Temporary URL's, which give the user access to the file for a specific amount of time, after which the URL becomes unusable.

A couple of things, if you are not concerned with file processing and trust the people uploading their files completely, you can upload directly to Amazon S3. However, I find it much easier to just upload to my server and do all of my processing, checking, and logging before taking the final step and putting the file on Amazon S3.

If you have any questions on the specifics of any of this, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

While Owens suggestion is an excellent one, there is another option you can consider - what you are describing is a Content Repository.

Since you have sufficient control of the server to be able to install a (non-commercial) piece of software, you may be interested in the [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/)* Content Repository. It even includes a Java API, so you should be able to control the software (at least as far as adding, and extracting content) from your Servlets.

*Actually, if you combine this idea with Owens and expand on it, you could actually host the repository on the Amazon S3 space, and use the free-tier Amazon EC2 instance to host the software itself. (Although, I understand that the free-tier EC2 instance is only free for the first year)*

HTH

NB. I'm sure other content repositories exist, but JackRabbit is the only one I've played with (albeit briefly).