# WMV file downloading in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp written in which i am downloading certain files... they are pdf, zip, ppt and wmv. All the file types works except wmv. I couldnt figure out problem. When i play wmv file i get following error.

> Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.

In my jps i have written code as following

```
response.setContentType("video/x-ms-wmv");
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=123.wmv;");
String fileName                 = "/logs/164266828.wmv";
FileInputStream input           = new FileInputStream(fileName);
BufferedInputStream buf         = new BufferedInputStream(input);
int readBytes                   = 0;
ServletOutputStream myOut       = response.getOutputStream( );
while((readBytes = buf.read( )) != -1)
    myOut.write(readBytes);
```

Any inputs or modifications would be of great help !!!

Comment: At least "response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");" is not needed or even harmful.

Comment: ok... but you find anything missing in code for wmv file types? thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use JSP to stream binary data. JSP may have corrupted it with template text (whitespace and so on outside those `<% %>` things). Move this code to the `doGet()` method of a servlet class and invoke the servlet instead of JSP.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, those files seems static files. You don't necessarily need a servlet for this if you have full control over your server. In case of for example Tomcat, you could add the folder with the static files as another `<Context>` to the `server.xml` file.

#### See also:

- [Reliable data serving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502841/reliable-data-serving)
- [Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java-w)