# Can I cache an HTML img, whose source is pointing to a java servlet thats generating it on the fly?

Tags: java, html, servlets

In my project we use some img tags like that

```
<img src="url to java servlet?parameters">
```

while the servlet responds the bytesteam right away, something like

```
response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);
```

That all works fine, but is there any way of caching that image in the browser, because it wont cache it automatically like regular url images.

Comment: What's the content-type of the HTTP-response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set at least the [`ETag`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19), [`Last-Modified`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) and [`Expires`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) headers on the response. The `ETag` header should represent the unique identifier of the file based on a combination of filename, filesize and lastmodified timestamp). The `Last-Modified` header should represent the last modified timestamp of the file. The `Expires` header should inform the client how long it is allowed to keep the file in cache.

If the cache has been expired in the client side and the `ETag` or `Last-Modified` are available, then the client will send a `HEAD` request to check if the file needs to be renewed. If not, then the `Expires` will just be postponed again accordingly.

You can find here a servlet example which handles this all (and download resumes and automatic GZIP): [FileServlet supporting resume and GZIP](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html).

However, if your files are available on the disk file system already (and not in a database), then you should consider just delegating the job to the servletcontainer's builtin default servlet. See also [Reliable data serving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502841/reliable-data-serving).

Answer (score 2):

See the [Caching Tutorial for Web Authors and Webmasters](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

You want to output suitable Cache-Control headers and/or handle If-Modified-Since and/or ETag requests.

Answer (score 1):

Your servlet should provide logic for `if-modified-since`, `expired` logic. See [`getLastModified`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#getLastModified%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) method.