# JSF / Primefaces Link to Filesystem

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, wildfly-10

I have a WebApplication, where I have to provide direct access to a mounted network drive on the client side (e.g. `\\server\zentrale` mapped to drive `Z:\`).

I tried following, but nothing works:

```
<a target="_blank" href="file:///server/zentrale/username/data">user files</a>
<h:outputlink target="_blank" value="file:///server/zentrale/username/data">user files</a>

<a target="_blank" href="file:///Z:/username/data">user files</a>
<h:outputlink target="_blank" value="file:///Z:/username/data">user files</a>
```

I also added `<disable-cross-context>false</disable-cross-context>` in my `jboss-web.xml` - without success.

@BalusC mentioned in [JSF 2 and a link to file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435574/jsf-2-and-a-link-to-file-system)  to create a new webapp context. 
So, how can I do this using WildFly 10 and Primefaces 6.1 ?

In an older version of our WebApplication we used the `IE View` plugin for Firefox, but this was last updated in 2013! Because we have to support other browser like Chrome and IE, we don't want to be dependent on some browser plugins!

Comment: This will **never** work in decent browsers... Plain html security issue...  (try with a plain html file, won't work either). All this is mentioned in the link you refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In https://developer.jboss.org/thread/227893 I found a hint, how to get access to the local filesystem on the server side.

standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <location name="documents" handler="document-handler"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
    </server>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        <file name="document-handler" directory-listing="true" path="\\server\Zentrale\docments"/>
    </handlers>
</subsystem>
```

To achieve this using `jboss-cli.sh` use the following commands:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/location=documents:add(handler=document-handler)
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/file=document-handler:add(path=\\\\server\\Zentrale\\documents, directory-listing=true)
```

A click on each link in `page.xhtml` opens a new tab in the browser where I can navigate in the server's file system - even on shared folders!

page.xhtml

```
<a href="/documents/projects/project_4711/" target="_blank">Project 4711</a>
<h:outputLink value="/documents/projects/project_4711/" target="_blank">Project 4711</h:outputLink>
```

This is the solution for my problem, but yes - it does not allow me to navigate on the clients local filesystem!

Comment: Better to use a servlet for this (makes you app server independent)

Comment: Do have any hint how to do this with a servlet?

Comment: Yes, search stackoverflow and google. Lots of examples