# How can I insert image url in database using storedprocedure in mysql database?

Tags: java, spring, plsql, java-stored-procedures

How can I insert image URL in database using java stored procedure in MySQL database?

Comment: there is a chance to store fakepaths in database due to security issues while uploading images from local system, of course you can check once about query at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445648/how-to-store-only-image-path-url-in-database-rather-than-image-itself

Answer (score 0):

First Create Procedure with query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE setData
(imgURL IN varchar(200)) AS
BEGIN
insert into table_name values()  //write query here
END;
```

I Dont know what mysql version you are using, so query may be different for different database version.

Then Simply call the method by using callable statement

```
class DemoStoredProcedure
{
      public static void main(String args[])   
      {
             Connection conn = null;
             CallableStatement stmt = null;
             try
             {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("Your connection URL HREeee","usrname","password");
                    String sql = "{call setData (?)}";
                    stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
                    String url="images/a.jpg";
                    stmt.setString(1,url);
                    stmt.execute();
             }
             catch(Exception e)
              {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }
             finally
              {

                                             if(stmt!=null)
                                                    stmt.close();
                                                }catch(SQLException se2){
                                                      }
                                                 try{
                                         if(conn!=null)
                                              conn.close();
                                                 }catch(SQLException se){
                                        se.printStackTrace();

               }
      }
}
```

I hope I have done what you want, This way you can save the imgUrl to the database.