# How to display a user uploaded file?

Tags: spring, jsp

How can I display user uploaded files ?

I have some uploaded files on my local harddrive, but I cannot seem to display them with:
 `<img src="appcontext/uploads/file.jpg" />`.

When I try to view this from my browser, I get `file not found - error 404`. I'm wondering if this problem isn't because I'm building a REST application. Can I, in my `servlet-context.xml` , map a word to location ?

`<resorces mapping="/uploads/**" location="D:/uploads/" />`

or something like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reliable data serving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502841/reliable-data-serving)

Comment: @Fixus: your question is very confusing, I have read it several times and do still not understand what you are asking. So let me ask some question to understand it: 1) is it related to file upload? 2) where are the files located on hdd (in your web-app-directory)? 3) can you access the files from within your app (file access)?

Comment: @Ralph - sory for the confusing. 1) yes, cause those files are uploaded by user 2) no they, aren't located in my web-app directory. just on a hdd 3) hmm i`m not sure do I understand you. But I can't get them from my jsp template

Comment: @Fixus: Are the files uploaded through your application or through a other way?

Comment: @Ralph: users are uploading them via form

Comment: @Fixus: so you have a controller that save the file. -- You only need a second controller to download it.

Comment: @Ralph: yes I got a controller. I use there srcFile.transferTo(destFile); where transferTo is a method of MultipartFile. So I need a controller that has RequestMapping on /uploads/ and serve the file with model.addAttribute ?

Comment: @Fixus: no, no model attribute - see my extended answer.

Comment: @Ralph: but i want to display it on my site. So why user should download it ? o.O Maybe you missunderstood me. or maybe i'm missing something again :/

Comment: @Fixus: I assue the files are pictures: So diplayging pictures on your site mean that there is a `<img>` tag in your hthm, wich point to an url where the file can be get. Technical it is a download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to have a controller, that takes the file name as an argument. And then this controller returns the file (and not a rendered jsp like the most other ones).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> thumbnail(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name ) {
    File file = new File(BASEPATH + "/" + name);
    if (file.exists)) {
        byte[] content = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType("yourcontentType");
        headers.setContentLength(thumbnailContent.length);
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

**Attention: this simple example is a strong security issue**, a user could use this to download every file from the server where the tomcat has read access. Is is not restricted to the BASEPATH. (The attacker could send for example: name = "....\differentDir\secret.txt") -- One way to handle is is to use a whitelist of alloed chars (only A..Z, a..z, 0..9)

Comment: i've done everything as you wrote BUT nothing happens. My method isn't invoked. I've made RequesMapping(value = /uploads/{fileName") and it isn't working. I've also checked with mapping like in your example but still nothing. in my <img /> i got src like this /uploads/file.jpg

Comment: maybe it's because of apache tiles ?

Comment: hmm I've added new servlet mapping for path /uploads/ so now I can use this method. But I get only byte code on screen :) But i'm close :)

Comment: @Fixus: sorry for no response, I was in an internet free zone the whole day.

Comment: no way ? i thought that places like that are just in old books :) no problem. I`ve tested few solutions and it works great. rly big thx for your help and time