# How to write uploaded file to a folder inside web project?

Tags: jsp, file-upload, path

I am using Apache Commons File Uploader API. It is working successfully when I use absolute path like this `c:\\my uploads\\`. That is file will be uploaded to that place.

I am using NetBeans 7 for development. In my Project Tree, I have created another folder called `uploads`. So when I use relative paths like `uploads/` or `/uploads/pics/`, it is not working. That is, there is no error. But file is not written to that folder. I am using a object of "File" and using its "write()" function.

My project folder structure is like:

```
-- C:\
-- -- my project\
-- -- -- school\
-- -- -- -- web\
-- -- -- -- -- index.jsp
-- -- -- -- -- fileupload.jsp
-- -- -- -- -- uploads\
-- -- -- -- -- -- pics\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to convert the relative web path to absolute disk file system path by `ServletContext#getRealPath()`.

```
String relativeWebPath = "/uploads";
String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
File file = new File(absoluteDiskPath, filename);
// ...
```

However, this approach of writing uploaded files to expanded WAR folder is absolutely not recommended. When you redeploy the WAR, all those uploaded files will get lost (simply because they are not contained in the original WAR!). It will also not work when the server is configured to expand WAR in memory instead of on disk. The `getRealPath()` would then return `null`.

Write uploaded files to a path outside the expanded WAR folder. You did it right at first place. You can always make the upload folder configureable by specifying it as a VM argument or a properties file setting.

Last but not least, Java code belongs in Java classes, not JSP files.

Comment: thanku. I am going to use "C:\\my uploads\\" as the location. But how to check if folder exists ? If not exists, create one. Object of `File` contains `mkdir()`. But it do not accept a path. So I am confused

Comment: Just call it on `new File("C:/my uploads")`.

Comment: thanku. I am using it like this. But i did not know that it works like that way.

Comment: The `File` class is indeed a bad name as most developers incorrectly assume that it can only refer files, not folders. That class should be named `Path`. They have fixed it in Java 7.

Comment: thanku. I am using `File` like this: `File f = new File("c:\uploads\" + fileName)`. So this will an error when folder does not exists.

Comment: I think you're totally missing the point. Just create `File uploadFolder = new File("C:/my uploads")` and call `mkdir()` (or better, `mkdirs()`) on it. You can just do it once during servlet's initialization or something. Then you can use `File uploadedFile = new File(uploadFolder, filename)`.

Comment: one more question, how to display this image ? I am storing filename with extension in database. So i tried like this: `<img src="c:\my uploads\<%= fileName %>" />`. This will not work. Because when i checked page html, it still displays correct path `c:\my uploads\test.jpg`. But when hovered it shows target location as `localhost:8080/my project/c:\myuploads\test.jpg`. This is also not working: `../../../uploads/test.jpg`. It appends `localhost:8080/myproject/` in front of it.

Comment: The `<img src>` must refer an URL, not a local disk file system path. If you're using Tomcat, just add another `<Context>` to `server.xml`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502841/reliable-data-serving

Comment: thanku. I am using GlassFish Server(NetBeans 7.1). For MySQL, I am using WAMP Server. When i checked `sun-web.xml`, there is `<context-root>/myproject</context-root>`.

Comment: Add this line to `sun-web.xml`: `<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/uploads/* dir=C:/" />`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/primeface-update-after-upload/8889096#8889096 for a related answer.

Comment: thanku. I have done it like this: `<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/uploads/* dir=c:/uploads/" />` in xml file. Then used it like this: `<img src="/uploads/<%= fileName %>" />`. But this did not worked. When i checked that link (by hovering on it, in Google Chrome's Inspect Element), it showed: `http://localhost:8080/uploads/test.jpg`

Comment: Remove `/uploads` from `dir`. The `dir` must refer the parent location.

Comment: Code now: `<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/uploads/* dir=c:/" />`
JSP: `<img src="/uploads/<%= fileName %>" />`. Still image is not showing. My project is situated at `http://localhost:8080/myproject/index.jsp`. So is this problem caused because of not including that project name in XML config?