# Trying to optimize quicksort for larger files

Tags: python, quicksort

Does anyone know how I can optimize this code better to run larger files. It works with smaller inputs, but I need it to run a file with over 200,000 words. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

```
import random
import re

def quick_sort(a,i,n):
    if n <= 1:
        return
    mid = (len(a)) // 2
    x = a[random.randint(0,len(a)-1)]
    p = i - 1
    j = i
    q = i + n
    while j < q:
        if a[j] < x:
            p = p + 1
            a[j],a[p] = a[p],a[j]
            j = j + 1
        elif a[j] > x:
            q = q - 1
            a[j],a[q] = a[q],a[j]
        else:
            j = j + 1
    quick_sort(a,i,p-i+1)
    quick_sort(a,q,n-(q-i))

file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
my_list = []
with open(file_name,'r') as f:     
    for line in f:                     
        line = re.sub('[!#?,.:";\']', '', line).lower()
        token = line.split()    
        for t in token:
            my_list.append(t)

a = my_list
quick_sort(a,0,len(my_list))
print("List After Calling Quick Sort: ",a)
```

Comment: used sorted() or sort()

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918060/how-do-i-sort-very-large-files

Comment: @xdhmoore the thread you linked belongs to java category

Comment: @Joshua Varghese It does but it's a similar problem algorithmically.

Comment: Is there any solution to do this with quick sort in particular? My merge sort code works, but my quick sort isn't as successful. Also, I'm can't use functions like sort().

Comment: There seems to be a description of 'external quicksort' here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Variants

Comment: Decorate your function with `@functools.lru_cache()` (put it in the line above `def quick_sort():` and put `import functools` at top of file). For recursive intensive functions like yours it may help. Run it and see. If it doesn't help, you take 30s to undo this change :)

Comment: @functools.lur_cache() give me a type error "unhashable type: 'list'". I'll try the external quicksort and give you guys an update if it works.

Comment: @Niloct: Caching is inappropriate here. To start with, quicksort never recurses on the same arguments unless you call it more than once. And it modifies the list input in place, so two calls with the same arguments may need to do different things depending on the contents of the list each time (if the list was changed in between the calls, the second one needs to run, you can't rely upon the cached result).

Comment: @john1999: can you elaborate on what is going wrong with your code? Is it raising an exception? Giving the wrong results? Just taking too long?

Comment: So I keep having this error every time I try to run the larger file through it: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Comment: @Niloct: That's not what answers are for. And caching is not useful for a sorting program.

Comment: This issue isn't really related to the size of the input, a larger size just lets the bug (which I haven't fully identified yet) cause recursion errors. The real issue is something related to the `n` value you pass to later calls. Often you end up sorting the same sub-list a whole bunch of times.

Comment: Yeah so after some testing that is literally the issue. For some reason it keeps sorting the same sub-list even when it is already sorted.

Comment: Must you use a quicksort? If you can use a heap or PriorityQueue, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your random selection of an index to use for your pivot `x` is using the whole size of the input list `a`, not just the part you're supposed to be sorting on the current call. This means that very often your pivot won't be in the current section at all, and so you won't be able to usefully reduce your problem (because all of the values will be on the same side of the pivot). This leads to lots and lots of recursion, and for larger inputs you'll almost always hit the recursion cap.

The fix is simple, just change how you get `x`:

```
x = a[random.randrange(i, i+n)]
```

I like `randrange` a lot better than `randint`, but you could use `randint(i, i+n-1)` if you feel the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Must you use a quicksort? If you can use a `heapq` or `PriorityQueue`, the `.get`/(`.pop()`) methods automatically implement the sort:

```
import sys
from queue import PriorityQueue

pq = PriorityQueue()

inp = open(sys.stdin.fileno(), newline='\n')

#inp = ['dag', 'Rug', 'gob', 'kex', 'mog', 'Wes', 'pox', 'sec', 'ego', 'wah'] # for testing
for word in inp:
    word = word.rstrip('\n')
    pq.put(word)

while not pq.empty():
    print(pq.get())
```

Then test with some large random word input or file e.g.:

```
shuf /usr/share/dict/words | ./word_pq.py
```

where `shuf` is Gnu `/usr/local/bin/shuf`.

Comment: The `queue` module is for synchronized communication between multiple threads. For a single-threaded application like this one, you probably should use `heapq` directly (it's what is used by the `queue` module to implement `PriorityQueue`).