# Streaming larger files in java

Tags: file, streaming

We are streaming the files form server in zip format and writning into oracle blob object using pipedstreams.It is working fine to me some 300MB size.But i have the requirement to stor e the gatter than 2GB data.When i tried to store 1GB data it is failing.Please suggest me the better way to stream the larger size files in java.

--Thanks in Adv

Answer (score 0):

if your code fails around 300MB you most certainly have created faulty code - my guess is your JVM heap size is set to ~512MB and you only got ~300MB of free memory for your own purposes -- that is more than enough, just stream your file in small chunks (maybe about 1KiB or even 1MiB if you want) and you'll be good to go : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55788/351861