# upload file using servlet but in run time only

Tags: java, file, servlets, upload

I need to upload file to my web application using servlet, the problem is that I want the file to be available only in the run time !

I know to upload the file to the server, but I need the file to be available when the user upload the file to the web and do some tasks to the file and when he close the web application he will lose the file and need to upload it again

Would you please give me any tutorial to help me?

Comment: May be you are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709/streaming-large-files-in-a-java-servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`that delete the file when the user session is destroyed (see method `sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)`)

Hope it helps.