# How to download huge CSV file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I have a javascript file that requests for data from server.The data has to be displayed in CSV format. The data size can reach huge limits. 
The following is the code I am using in javascript to download the file.

```
var tmp = document.createElement('a');        
var csvData = new Blob([dataString], { type: 'text/csv' }); 
var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
tmp.href =  csvUrl;     
tmp.setAttribute('download', "abc.csv");
tmp.click();
```

The file size if it reaches 50MB crashes the chrome. The chrome gives "aw snap" error. But I should be able to download data more than 1GB. How to download such huge CSV file without crashing chrome browser.

Comment: You don't display or download 1Gb of data in browser. Basic solution would be to implement pagination and corresponding API to fetch only portions you need.

Comment: Why not? I want to save the data which is  in the server in client machine in CSV format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach of converting data to string and triggering click event was totally wrong. What really is required is to stream the file. The below link explains how to stream a file from HttpServlet's response object.

[Streaming large files in a java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709/streaming-large-files-in-a-java-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution [authored by Eli Grey](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js), [eligrey.com](http://eligrey.com) is to convert to blob and use [URL.createObjectURL(blob)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)