# Difference between AJAX request and form HTTP request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am follwing the below link to download a file in chrome browser

[Streaming large files in a java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709/streaming-large-files-in-a-java-servlet)

But the problem is that the file is getting downloaded when submit button in form is clicked, but if I send ajax request the file is not getting downloaded. I am not able to understand the problem. This is how my ajax request looks:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    dataType : "json",

});
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!